# How to put entire pc behinde Tor

Tags: socks

When I use Hotspot shield ( in full protection mode ) , my pc , entirely goes under anonymity and protection . How i can do the same thing in Tor . I want when successfully run tor browser , my entire network connection goes under protection and anonymity and my entire IP changed . Thanks

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to anonymize just your PC, or every device that uses your network connection (i.e. multiple PCs, phones, etc.)?

Comment: @Farid Abdi: `When I use Hotspot shield ( in full protection mode )` If you'd read what Edward Snowden told the world, you'd have steered clear of `Hotspot Shield` and its ilk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a physical device would be what you are looking for. Something like what the P.O.R.T.A.L. project hopes to accomplish.

These guys go over their ideas/philosophy and why this is a good thing in this Youtube video: [DEF CON 22 - Ryan Lackey & Marc Rogers & theGrugq - Masquerade](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grugq%20portal&search=Search)

Their github: https://github.com/grugq/portal

Unfortunately, I don't think they have produced anything yet. However, the Gl-iNET can run tor firmware and the firmware is available on their website. It's a Chinese company, and they sell on Amazon, and Amazon prime. I think this is the hardware that PORTAL is planning to use anyways.

[Gl.iNet Smart Router, Openwrt, 3g Modem, Tor, Mobile App Control, 16M Flash](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JKFE0FW)

Their website, which has the tor firmware (now including tor over wired lan): http://www.gl-inet.com/w/?page_id=676

---

There are a few other products that will do the same ting. You could roll your own with a Raspberry Pi or similar SBC (single board computer), or check out these guys:

- InvizBox seems to have the right idea:
  https://www.invizbox.io/
- Anonabox got the most pubilicity, and most of it was bad and they deserved it:
  https://anonabox.com/
  http://www.wired.com/2014/10/kickstarter-suspends-anonabox/

---

Here's a few links about using a Raspberry Pi to do the same thing, they call it "Onion Pi". This is not ideal though; you want network hardware, not a general purpose CPU to handle this stuff.

**How-tos:**

- https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview
- http://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/how-to-bake-an-onion-pi/

**Related How-tos**

- http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Tor-relay/
- http://lifehacker.com/5978098/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-personal-vpn-for-secure-browsing-anywhere-you-go

**Misc articles:**

- http://spectrum.ieee.org/geek-life/hands-on/a-diy-tor-wifi-access-point
- http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/onion-pi-turns-raspberry-pi-into-tor-proxy-and-wireless-access-point/
- https://raspberrypi.org/onion-pi-tor-proxy/
- http://boingboing.net/2013/06/17/onion-pi-convert-a-raspberry.html

Comment: maybe for just a few tasks [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/) would be a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). If you use something like a router you should make sure you never have the PC that you use ever send any kind of information that relates to you. This can be extremely hard, especially if you didn't install a new operating system, etc. on that system and never set personally identifying information.

I would also make sure that you do some checkups, like at least [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) to make sure you don't carry around information that distinguishes you from others, because in that case any small mistake and accidental leak of information could be disastrous, even for things you used that PC for in the past.