# Possible to run Tor router in headless ARM server

Tags: linux, server

I would like to know if its possible to use the Tor router in a headless (no GUI, only SSH access) server, in order to provide a simple access point to the Onion network, and Internet in general to services running within the server?

Furthermore, would it be possible to run Tor in the ARM architecture, like Raspberry Pi, Banana Pi, Beaglebone and so on?

Appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by "headless server" and "headless services"?

Comment: Yes, you can run Tor on a Raspberry Pi. Googling "tor raspberry pi" is a good place to start. If you use the search bar at the top right of this page then you can also browse previous questions on the topic. Do you want to run it as a relay, or host a hidden service?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks: I mean headless in its natural meaning. No GUI. I'm not entirely familiar with Tor terminology. But I would require  the normal operation of Tor, like anyone has when browsing the web through Tor Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure is it possible to run Tor headless also on an ARM server! (although i'm not sure if every ARM platform has precompiled packages...)

for example here is a very detailed guide for the Raspberry Pi:
https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview
or a script collection to made installing/handling easier:
https://github.com/spiegelonline/sponionpi (partly german)

or there are also dedicated devices like the [InvizBox](https://www.invizbox.io/).

Comment: maybe also interesting links: http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7265/5234

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to run Tor on such box, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it's impossible to configure full disk encryption on it (unless you have another box with compatible CPU and video output, even virtual).

And if you use Tor for **really sensitive activities**, then you really need to encrypt all disks to avoid sharing the fate of Ross Ulbricht.